# ReactJs - Combine multiple style objects immutably

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I have the following inline style object:**

```
const simpleCarousel = {
   toggle: {
     ....
  },
  toggle_prev: {
    left: 0
  },
  toggle_next: {
    right: 0
  }
};
```

**With the following standard CSS markup:**

```
    <div className="toggle, toggle_prev">Prev</div>
    <div className="toggle, toggle_next">Next</div>
```

**I want to use inline styles and combine the objects:**

```
    <div style={ Object.assign(simpleCarousel.toggle, simpleCarousel.toggle_prev) }>
    Prev</div>
    <div style={ Object.assign(simpleCarousel.toggle, simpleCarousel.toggle_next) }>
    Next</div>
```

However, now toggle_prev and toggle_next both share `left:0 & right:0`

**Question:**

Short of immutable.js, in ES6/ES7 how can I combine my inline style objects immutably?

**Update to Brandon request, this is not working:**

```
  <div className="controls">
    <div style={ ...simpleCarousel.toggle, ...simpleCarousel.toggle_prev }>
     Prev</div>
    <div style={ ...simpleCarousel.toggle, ...simpleCarousel.toggle_prev }>
     Next</div>
  </div>
```

Module build failed: SyntaxError:

**Ah HA!!! This works !!**

```
 <div style={ { ...simpleCarousel.toggle, ...simpleCarousel.toggle_prev } }> Prev</div>
 <div style={ { ...simpleCarousel.toggle, ...simpleCarousel.toggle_next } }> Next</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object spread operator:

```
const a = { a: 1 };
const b = { b: 2, foo: "foo" };
const c = { foo: "override" };

// { a: 1, b: 2, foo: "override" };
const abc = { ...a, ...b, ...c };

// { a: 10, b: 2, foo: "override" };
const xyz = { ...abc, a: 10 };
```

More info: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you, this is not working for me:                  <div style={ ...simpleCarousel.toggle, ...simpleCarousel.toggle_prev } > ...

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to tweak your Object.assign call. It takes the properties from subsequent objects and adds them to the first one. So supply a new object to assign to each time and:

```
<div style={ Object.assign({}, simpleCarousel.toggle, simpleCarousel.toggle_prev) }>
Prev</div>
<div style={ Object.assign({}, simpleCarousel.toggle, simpleCarousel.toggle_next) }>
Next</div>
```

Should do what you want. Note the extra `{}` as the first parameter to Object.assign.